# Why diskmgmt shows many partitions when its the same partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Diskmgmt shows many partitions on DISK 0 when it's the same partition, why is that happening?
Also when I select one of those so called partitions it highlights all the partitions.

I included a photo to show this thing.

[image]

This thing started when I shrank my main partition, and created a partition   and after that I deleted that partition and extended the main one. Basically doing this couple of times made this issue.

Is this a bug or known behavior?

Comment: Probably because it's like LVM in Linux -- unlike partition, each volume in a dynamic disk can make use of non-contiguous block ranges of the disk, and the mapping of a volume to its block ranges might be "out of order" as well after all the operations, so they are considered separate ranges even when some of them are contiguous.

Comment: volume =/= partition

Comment: Yeah, but I still don't get it, why when I removed the partition it shows that it's like a partition. There is any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You have formatted your disks as Dynamic, so what you see is
entirely normal. Partition E spans several allocation segments.

Disk 0 seems empty, so I suggest reformatting it as Basic,
which will be simpler to manage
(unless you have good reasons for its being Dynamic).

For information see the article
[Basic and Dynamic Disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks).

(I'm not too happy with disk 1 being Dynamic, but this can't be
changed without the re-installation of Windows.)

Comment: The reason i made it dynamic is because I wanted to make a mirrored partition RAID 1.
Also, DISK 0 is not empty, look above, it has 9% free space.

Comment: For RAID 1 under Windows, see [Storage Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/storage-spaces-in-windows-b6c8b540-b8d8-fb8a-e7ab-4a75ba11f9f2#WindowsVersion=Windows_10). Personally, I prefer good backups over time rather than such mechanisms.